# Mockito returning null value for Future

Tags: mockito, playframework-2.6

I am unit-testing a `controller` in a `play-framework` application.

The `controller` uses a repository and I am mocking the repository as follows

```
val mockUserRepository = mock(classOf[UsersRepository])
  when(mockUserRepository.findOne(userKeys)).thenReturn(Future{Some(user)})
  when(mockUserRepository.save(user)).thenReturn(Future(Some(user)))
```

Then I run the following test. In the test, `controller.signupUser(request)` calls the `findOne` method of the repository as follows

```
val findUserFuture: Future[Option[User]] = userRepo.findOne(userKeys) 

        println("user future is ",findUserFuture)
        findUserFuture.flatMap { (userOption: Option[User]) => //this crashes because findUserFuture is null)
```

But `findOne` returns a `null` instead of a dummy `Future{user}`

```
"User signup request with body" should {
    "return OK and user profile if the signup profile data is correct" in {


      val jsonBody = Json.parse(
        """
          {
             "external-profile":{
                "email":"test@test.com",
                "firstname":"fn",
                "lastname":"ln",
                "password":"aA1!1111"
             }
          }
        """)
      //val jsonBody = Json.toJson(signupInfo)
      val request: Request[AnyContentAsJson] = FakeRequest("POST", "ws/users/signup",Headers(("someH"->"someV")),new AnyContentAsJson(jsonBody))
      println("sending sign up request ", request)
      //request.body = signupInfo
      val response: Future[Result] = controller.signupUser(request)
      val responseBodyAsJsValue:JsValue = contentAsJson(response)
      println("received response of sign up ", responseBodyAsJsValue)

    }
  }
```

error
received profile

```
UserProfile(None,ExternalUserProfile(test@test.com,fn,ln,Some(aA1!1111)))
checking if the user with the following details exists LoginInfo(credentials,test@test.com)
returning id 116 for name test@test.com
(user future is ,null)

java.lang.NullPointerException was thrown.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at controllers.UserController.$anonfun$signupUser$1(UserController.scala:116)
```

What I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The issue apparently was the I wasn't using `when` correctly.
I read that "
Mockito allows to configure the return values of its mocks via a fluent API. Unspecified method calls return "empty" values:

null for objects

0 for numbers

false for boolean

empty collections for collections

Mocks can return different values depending on arguments passed into a method. The when(…​.).thenReturn(…​.) method chain is used to specify a a return value for a method call with pre-defined parameters.
"

`when` expects the method as well as the exact arguments. So if I want to call `findUser(userkey)` where `userkey`'s value is say `1` in the actual call then I need to write `when(findUser(1))` or `userKey=1; findUser(userKey))`.

In my wrong implementation, I had set `userkey` as

UserKeys(1,"test@test.com",loginInfo,"","")

but the call to `findUser` was with value

UserKeys(116,"d@d.com",loginInfo,"fn","ln")

I changed the userkey value in test and it worked

```
val userKeys = UserKeys(utilities.bucketIDFromEmail(email)/*returns 116*/,"d@d.com",loginInfo,"fn","ln")

      when(mockUserRepository.findOne(userKeys)).thenReturn(Future{Some(user)})
      when(mockUserRepository.save(user)).thenReturn(Future(Some(user)))
```